# How to open an article from menu item in a popup window?

Tags: joomla

I need to open an article from a menu in a 800x600 popup window.

Any idea on how to achieve that?

Comment: You want to open an article in a popup window?

Comment: @yarek if you are doing Joomla development please join us at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an extension called [Modals](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/style-a-design/popups-a-iframes/modals/), once it has been installed, go to you menu item and let's **edit the title**, for example if our menu item is called *"About us"*, add this tags:

```
{modal}About Us{/modal}
```

Now let'd add the size for the window:

```
{modal width="800" height="600"}About Us{/modal}
```